# Type checking a promise (using void or not?)

Tags: typescript

For a generic request function, which returns a Promise. How should you handle the catch?

It feels as if I should have 'void'. But then picking the values up provides an error.

```
const request = async function<T>(url: string, context = ''): Promise<T | void> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json() as Promise<T>)
    .catch(err => {
      // this part is void?
      console.warn('Failed to load fetch.');
    });
};

const params = await request<{ relations: { name: string; }[] } | void>('https://www.example.com');

params.relations.filter(( relation ) => {
  console.log(relation);
});

// Error:
// Property 'relations' does not exist on type 'void | { relations: { name: string; }[] }'.
// Property 'relations' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

Comment: `catch` block in `request` function is unnecessary. Let the calling code handle the error. `request` function should just return the `Promise` returned by calling `fetch` or the `Promise` returned by `fetch(...).then(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `request` converts rejection into fulfillment with `undefined`, you need a guard when calling it, e.g.:

```
const params = await request<{ relations: { name: string; }[] } | void>('https://www.example.com');
if (!params) {
    // It didn't work
} else {
    params.relations.filter(( relation ) => {
        console.log(relation);
    });
}
```

**but**, in general it's best **not** to convert rejection into fulfillment, so that the caller can differentiate them with `try`/`catch` or let rejection propagate, etc. This is particularly useful with `async` functions (which you appear to be using given your use of `await`, since rejections propagate exactly like things thrown with `throw` do.

So I'd remove that part of `request`, which also lets you remove the `| void`:

```
const request = async function<T>(url: string, context = ''): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json() as Promise<T>);
};
```

Then you don't need the guard when you use it, and you don't use `| void` in the type parameter when calling it:

```
const params = await request<{ relations: { name: string; }[] }>('https://www.example.com');

params.relations.filter(( relation ) => {
    console.log(relation);
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwI4FcHRgXhgQwgTzGBgDMUioBLcAHgBUA%20AChTgBsAuGaOSsAcwA0MUGCgIAHrGwByGQEouABTggAtpQgJ6DGAG8AUDHgIorMKVPAAFi3byjxmADoo1hGCaIIWXYacBMJQkMEwAhN7OIADW8vqOgYFuqgDuMGAIaQCicKpwTABEABJ0dEowCLkgcDAFMADUJhDO0DhmEPIA3AmBAL49AYhmcBaRAFYQ4ExxeDAq6prajN0BvV0Gvd0GeITEZBTUFpI4agAObAjT8QGiGKc4cCc%202DgpOJSwiKjoUDR6Jmw2ocIFx-mATgguDw%20PxOjBegBtAC68OYMmsUCgpxBAHocSkCc5jmcLs5QGoFFsAvdHmpmohAVRwM0SJQ2OJ8kwAUDwDA4pg-AMnLcQKS2CB%20F4EIzDutVut%20kA)

---

Side note: That code is falling prey to the `fetch` API footgun: `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors. You have to check for HTTP success yourself:

```
const request = async function<T>(url: string, context = ''): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
        }
        return res.json() as Promise<T>;
    });
};
```

Comment: (FWIW, I talk about handling errors with promises correctly -- including letting them propagate -- in Chapter 8 of my new book. Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for the additional info, very helpful. Am going to check out your book. One thing though, when I try out the last example with the error thrown, shouldn't that have 'void' again for when the Error is thrown? (my IDE is complaining "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'T'.")

Comment: @Remi - No, the `Promise` type's type parameter is only about its *fulfillment value*, not its *rejection reason*. Rejections aren't typed in TypeScript's definition of the `Promise` type. The error you're getting from the IDE is probably because of the `| void` when you call `request`. I've updated the answer to show rather than just implying the call syntax, and added a link to the TypeScript playground. :-)

Comment: (I should note that the lack of a type param for rejections seems odd to me. I'd expect `Promise` to take an optional second type parameter, like `Promise<F = void, R = Error>`. But it doesn't. The TypeScript folks are pretty bright so they probably have a reason, but...)